# AJAX - scripts don't work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to achieve - when I click on *link* **Name of movie**, getSummary function is called and iframe.php data is shown in *summary* div. The following code works, but, there is a problem. Scripts (like datepicker in this case) in *summary* div won't work (however they are still working in div's which aren't made through ajax). What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for taking a look!

**index.php**:

```
    <html>
        <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    ... other scripts ...

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSummary(id)
    {
       $.ajax({

         type: "GET",
         url: 'include/iframe.php',
         data: "id=" + id, // appears as $_GET['id'] @ ur backend side
         success: function(data) {
               // data is ur summary
              $('#summary').html(data);
         }

       });

    }
    </script>
    </head>
        <body>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="movie" onclick="getSummary(2)">Name of movie</a <br/>

    <div id="summary">Here is summary of movie</div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

**include/iframe.php**:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
              <fieldset>
                <div class="input-prepend">
                  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" name="range" id="range" />
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you need to bind the event listener after the dom has been added to the document. or alternativly using the on binding instead http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reinitalize the datapicker plugin?
However if you need to handle events like "click" you need to bind it: `$(elementcontainer).on("click","elementtoclick",function (){...})`